# How to select first row record of a specified query in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to select one row from the duplicate row result

i have two tables called books and library

Library Table

```
id    name        
 1     Php
 2    laravel
 3    react js
 4    node js
```

Books Table

```
  id    library_id    user_id          
   1       1          3
   2       1          3    
   3       2          8 
   4       2          8
   5       3          9
```

so am using join to select the name column from the library table using the library_id as foreign key in the book tables id

i want to select only one row that has the library_id of either 1 or 2 or any book id

Like this

```
 id   name  library_id 
 1     php     1

2    laravel   2

3    react js   3
```

i tried this below but it gives me duplicate rows

```
$user_id = auth()->user()->id
   DB::table('books')
    ->join('library', 'books.library_id', '=','library.id')
    ->where('user_id',$user_id))
    ->distinct('library_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Did you try `groupBy('library_id')`?

Comment: i got an error Syntax error or access violation: 1055

Comment: first call `get()` and then `groupBy('library_id')`

Comment: i got another error 'does not exist on this collection instance.'

Comment: Try with `'books.library_id'` instead of `'library_id'`

Comment: Sure i tried both ways, and still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use

```
$user_id = auth()->user()->id;
DB::table('books')
    ->join('library', 'books.library_id', '=','library.id')
    ->where('user_id','=',$user_id)
    ->distinct('library_id')
    ->get();
```

instead of

```
DB::table('books')
    ->join('library', 'books.library_id', '=','library.id')
    ->where('user_id',$user_id))
    ->distinct('library_id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
DB::table('library')
 ->select('library.id','name')
 ->whereIn('library.id', function($q) use ($user_id){
   $q->from('books')
    ->select('books.id')
    ->where('books.user_id',$user_id);
 })
 ->get();
```